# How to change focus from window to popup window using selenium. focus change from parent window to popup. Here is my python code which does not work

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

'''
'from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
LINK = "https://tinder.com/"
dev = 'C:\development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=dev)
driver.get(LINK)
sleep(5)
login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="s1362659109"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]')
login.click()
sleep(2)

```
base_window = driver.window_handles[0]
Facebook = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="s- 
365721967"]/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/span/div[2]/button')
Facebook.click()
sleep(2)
fb_login_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(fb_login_window)
print(driver.title)'
```

'''

Comment: use window_handle to get the current, after a new window is opened check window_handles by iterating and finding the handle that is not current.  HOWEVER, this probably is not a new tab/window.  More likely it's just a modal-style div tag.

Comment: can you give me the code ??? please.